# Can prophets make mistakes?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Can prophets make mistakes? (Not sins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the prophets can make misstakes but they dont sin and we have multiple encounters where prophets mad mistake. The Nabi Suliman where his wealth and his power made him forget about the akhira (not that he sined but that he got attached to the world). Other story is when a blind man came to the prophet seeking to convert to islam and the prophet pbuh was making da'ua to one of the tripe leaders so when the old man came to the prophet to prophet pbuh got annoyed and then Allah swt sent the verse

> He frowned and turned ˹his attention˺ away,˹simply˺ because the blind man came to him ˹interrupting˺.1You never know ˹O Prophet˺, perhaps he may be purified,or he may be mindful, benefitting from the reminder

Quran 80:1-4

So yes a prophet can be misstaken but not the point on sin.